# onClickListener vs onClick()

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-xml

If we are calling both `onClickListener` and the `onClick()` method from xml, then always `onClickListener` method is being called.
Why is it so ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button buttonCheck;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTesting);
    buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Click Listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("OnClick", "Called");
        }
    });
}
public void checkStatus(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On checkStatus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("checkStatus", "Called");
}

}
```

xml layout:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTesting"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
    android:onClick="checkStatus"
    android:text="Check" />
```

Comment: because it is a single listener ... and using `android:onClick` is just a shortcut for this ... so first you set the listener from xml in inflate/setContentView then you override it with your own setOnClickListener call

Comment: It's nearly the same as setting a background from the xml layout OR from the Java code. But this is a listener event, not a property.

Comment: too basic , please google

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onClick` in `xml` just calls through to `setOnClickListener` when the View is created. When you then call `setOnClickListener` in code, it overrides the existing `OnClickListener` that was set in `xml`.

Comment: obvious, but good answer :)

Comment: Thanks, it seems a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because while inflating from xmlwhen Button class constructor is called it will set onClick method as checkStatus.
Now you are overriding this in your activity's onCreate. 
Hence the later one is onClick that will getCalled.